# invalid attempt to read when reader is closed

Tags: c#, mysql

Estoy teniendo problemas con una excepcion que me arroja una aplicacion que estoy desarrollando con c# y MySQL.
El la excepcion es: "invalid attempt to read when reader is closed." y me ocurre cuando ingreso por segunda vez un codigo que debe buscar en una tabla de mi bd.

Esta excepcion pasa cuando ingreso un codigo que no esta registrado en la bd o si ya esta repetido, pero si no esta registrado en la bd no deberia guardarlo y lo hace, y si esta repetido, actualiza dos campos segun el codigo que se ingreso(cosa que si debe hacer) pero igualmente me lanza esta excepcion en el metodo camion_shown.
Mi codigo es el siguiente, utilizo dos Forms, si necesitan que me explaye mas con mi codigo favor de comentarmelo, muchas gracias.

**Form1 (No hay mucho que ver)**

```
namespace BasculaCañera
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {


        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 fr2 = new Form2();
            fr2.Show();
        }

        public String texto, codigo, aux, cuerpo = "";
        public char cabeza;




        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyChar == Convert.ToChar(Keys.Enter)) //Si el textbox detecta un enter, entra a esta condición.
            {



                texto = textBox1.Text;
                codigo = texto;
                textBox2.Text = codigo;
                textBox1.Text = "";
                cuerpo = "";
                var arreglo = codigo.ToCharArray(); //convierte la cadena en un arreglo de carácteres
                cabeza = arreglo[0];               //para guardar el primer carácter en una variable.


                for(int i = 1; i < arreglo.Length; i++)
                {
                    aux = Char.ToString(arreglo[i]);
                    cuerpo += aux;

                }  //Arreglo para juntar denuevo todo el cuerpo de la palabra(Sin la cabeza).

                if(cabeza=='B')
                {
                    if (cuerpo.Length == 6)
                    {
                        textBox3.Text = Char.ToString(cabeza);
                        textBox4.Text = cuerpo;
                        label1.Text = "Alzadora";
                        label3.Text = cuerpo;

                    }


                    if (cuerpo.Length != 6)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Codigo incorrecto");
                    }
                }

                if (cabeza == 'C')
                {
                    if (cuerpo.Length == 6)
                    {
                        textBox3.Text = Char.ToString(cabeza);
                        textBox4.Text = cuerpo;
                        label1.Text = "Cabo";
                        label3.Text = cuerpo;
                    }
                    if (cuerpo.Length != 6)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Codigo incorrecto");

                    }
                }

                if (cabeza == 'D')
                {
                    if (cuerpo.Length == 7)
                    {
                        textBox3.Text = Char.ToString(cabeza);
                        textBox4.Text = cuerpo;
                        label1.Text = "Camion";
                        label3.Text = cuerpo;

                        Camion cam = new Camion(cuerpo, cabeza);


                            cam.Show();
                            Console.WriteLine(codigo);
                            Console.WriteLine(cabeza);
                            Console.WriteLine(cuerpo);


                    }



                    if (cuerpo.Length != 7)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Codigo incorrecto"); Console.WriteLine(codigo);
                        Console.WriteLine(cabeza);
                        Console.WriteLine(cuerpo);
                    }
                }


                if (cabeza != 'B' && cabeza != 'C' && cabeza != 'D')
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Codigo incorrecto");
                }










            }
        }


    }
}
```

**Camion**

```
namespace BasculaCañera
{
    public partial class Camion : Form
    {
        //192.168.120.49
        MySqlCommand Query = new MySqlCommand();
        MySqlCommand Query2 = new MySqlCommand();
        MySqlConnection Conexion;
        MySqlDataReader consultar;
        public static MySqlConnection cnx = new MySqlConnection("server = localhost; database=estetica; Uid=root; pwd=;");
        public string sql = "server=localhost; database=bascula; Uid=root; pwd=;";
        DataTable tmp = new DataTable();
        string getCuerpo;
        char getCabeza;


        public Camion(string Cuerpo, char Cabeza)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            getCuerpo = Cuerpo;
            getCabeza = Cabeza;
        }

        private void Camion_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = getCabeza + getCuerpo;
            try
            {
                string Codigo, Chofer, Camion, Placas;

                Conexion = new MySqlConnection();
                Conexion.ConnectionString = sql;
                Conexion.Open();
                Query.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM estetica.camion where Codigo='" + textBox1.Text + "';";
                Query.Connection = Conexion;
                consultar = Query.ExecuteReader();

                while (consultar.Read())
                {                  
                    Codigo = consultar.GetString(1);
                    Chofer = consultar.GetString(2);
                    Camion = consultar.GetString(3);
                    Placas = consultar.GetString(4);

                    if (consultar.HasRows)
                    {
                        textBox2.Text = Chofer;
                        textBox3.Text = Camion;
                        textBox4.Text = Placas;
                        Conexion.Close();


                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("El codigo no contiene información");
                        Conexion.Close();
                        this.Close();


                    }
                }

            }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }


        }

        private void Camion_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Conexion = new MySqlConnection();
            Conexion.ConnectionString = sql;
            Conexion.Open();
            Query.CommandText = "select count(*) from bascula.camion where Codigo='" + getCabeza + getCuerpo + "';";
            Query.Connection = Conexion;
            consultar = Query.ExecuteReader();



            while (consultar.Read())
            {

                int count;
                count = consultar.GetInt32(0);

                if (count == 0)
                {
                    agregar();
                }
                else
                {
                    modificar();
                }




            }


        }

        public void modificar()
        {
            try
            {
                Conexion = new MySqlConnection();
                Conexion.ConnectionString = sql;
                Conexion.Open();
                Query.CommandText = "select count(*) from bascula.camion where Codigo='" + textBox1.Text + " and PesoSalida=0';";
                Query.Connection = Conexion;
                consultar = Query.ExecuteReader();

                while (consultar.Read())
                {
                    int count;
                    count = consultar.GetInt32(0);

                    if (count == 0)
                    {
                        agregarPesos();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Este código ya no puede utilizarse");
                        this.Close();
                    }
                }
                Conexion.Close();
            }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void agregarPesos()
        {
            int maximo;
            Conexion = new MySqlConnection();
            Conexion.ConnectionString = sql;
            Conexion.Open();
            Query.CommandText = "SELECT PesoEntrada FROM bascula.camion where Codigo='" + getCabeza+getCuerpo + "';";
            Query.Connection = Conexion;
            consultar = Query.ExecuteReader();

            while (consultar.Read())
            {

                maximo = consultar.GetInt32(0);
                Random rnd = new Random();
                int pesoSalida = rnd.Next(50000, maximo);
                int pesoNeto = maximo - pesoSalida;

                MySqlDataAdapter msj = new MySqlDataAdapter("UPDATE `bascula`.`camion` SET `PesoSalida`='" + pesoSalida + " ', `PesoNeto`='" + pesoNeto + "' WHERE `Codigo`='" + getCabeza+getCuerpo + "';", cnx);
                try
                {
                    cnx.Open();
                    msj.Fill(tmp);
                    cnx.Close();

                }
                catch (Exception r)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(r.Message);
                }
                finally { cnx.Close(); }


            }
            Conexion.Close();

        }

        public void agregar()
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            var PesoEntrada = rnd.Next(50000, 59000);

            bool cerrado = false;

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox2.Text) && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox3.Text) && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox4.Text))
            {
                cerrar();
                MessageBox.Show("Codigo no encontrado");
                cerrado = true;

            }

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox2.Text) && cerrado == false)
            {
                cerrar();
                MessageBox.Show("Chofer no encontrado");
                cerrado = true;


            }
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox3.Text) && cerrado == false)
            {
                cerrar();
                MessageBox.Show("Camion no encontrado");
                cerrado = true;

            }
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox4.Text) && cerrado == false)
            {
                cerrar();
                MessageBox.Show("Placas no encontradas");
                cerrado = true;

            }


            MySqlDataAdapter msj = new MySqlDataAdapter("INSERT INTO `bascula`.`camion` (`Codigo`, `PesoEntrada`, `Chofer`, `Camion`, `Placas`) VALUES ('" + getCabeza + getCuerpo + "', '" + PesoEntrada + "', '" + textBox2.Text + "', '" + textBox3.Text + "', '" + textBox4.Text + "');", cnx);
            try
            {
                cnx.Open();
                msj.Fill(tmp);
                cnx.Close();
                this.Close();

            }
            catch (Exception r)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(r.Message);
            }
            finally { cnx.Close(); }




        }

        private void cerrar()
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Deberias indicar en que parte del codigo te lanza el error, ademas te invito aque hagas el [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que conozcas mas sobre el sitio y ganes tu primera medalla.

Comment: No he profundizado mucho en la lectura de tu código pero segun el nombre del error el problema a simple vista puede que se deba a que estas intentando leer de la BD por segunda vez estando la conexión cerrada, o sea, habiendo cerrado la conexión la vez anterior que la usaste. Revisa que tengas bien esos detalles de apertura y cierre de conexiones

Comment: `reader is closed` = no has abierto la conexión cuando se ejecuta. Te sugiero revisar mejor tu lógica. Antes de ejecutar cualquier consulta, revisa si la conexión está abierta.

Comment: -Luis Fernando: El problema surge en consultar.reader(), al momento de insertar un codigo que ya existe,como lo comentaba en mi post. Ya realice el tour, muchas gracias.

Comment: - Adriana Hernandez: Antes de preguntar, investigue, y encontre que podia ser por que estaba cerrada la conexion, pero la verdad es que como voy empezando, me centro mucho a los ejemplos que encuentro pues me falta experiencia, asi que si encuentro un ejemplo de como hacer una consulta donde primero se abre la conexion, se realiza la consulta y despues se cierra la conexion es lo que utilizo, pues como comentaba, me falta experiencia utilizando estos comandos y ahi me gustaria que me ayudaran en eso.

Comment: -Mauricio Arias: Si, lo se. Mi codigo esta muy desordenado y me pierdo entre tantas conexiones que para mi eran necesarias (Algo que gracias a ustedes me doy cuenta que es un tremendo error). Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debo comentar que esta bastante desarodenado el codigo, tienes objetos de conexion definidos a nivel global en el form y otros los defines en cada metodo, al no se consitente seguro te no estas realizando el `open()` de una conexion antes de ejecutar el command

Recomendaria que programes en capas, al menos que sean dos capas, la capa de datos tendra el manejo de los datos y asi no tendras el codigo de ado.net en el mismo form

[[WinForms] Edición Empleados](http://ltuttini.blogspot.com.ar/2011/02/winforms-edicion-empleados-grabar.html)

en el articulo explico como debes programar esta capa.

Ademas tienes que usar parametros en el codigo, concatenar los valores en el string no es una buena practica.

El problema se presenta en `Camion_Shown` ya que estas invocando `modificar()`, pero en mabs metodos usas el mismo command y reader globales, por lo tanto si en `modifica()` realizar el `Close()` estas cerrando el mismo objeto

```
private string connstring = "server=localhost; database=bascula; Uid=root; pwd=;";

private void Camion_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    using(MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connstring))
    {
        conn.Open();

        string query = "select count(*) from bascula.camion where Codigo= ?codigo";
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?codigo", getCabeza + getCuerpo);

        MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            int count = consultar.GetInt32(0);

            if (count == 0)
            {
                agregar();
            }
            else
            {
                modificar();
            }
        }

    }   

}

public void modificar()
{
    try
    {

        using(MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connstring))
        {
            conn.Open();

            string query = "select count(*) from bascula.camion where Codigo= ?codigo and PesoSalida=0";
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?codigo", textBox1.Text);

            MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                int count = consultar.GetInt32(0);

                if (count == 0)
                {
                    agregarPesos();
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Este código ya no puede utilizarse");
                    this.Close();
                }
            }

        }

    }
    catch (MySqlException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

analiza la estructura de este ejemplo que adapta en base a tu codigo, aplicalo en `agregarPesos()`

Define siempre los objetos de conexion a la db de forma local, quita los que estan global al form

---

No quise cambiar tanto el codigo, pero si en el query defines un `COUNT` puedes usar el `ExecuteScalar()`, como en este ejemplo

```
private void Camion_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    using(MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connstring))
    {
        conn.Open();

        string query = "select count(*) from bascula.camion where Codigo= ?codigo";
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?codigo", getCabeza + getCuerpo);

        int count = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());

        if (count == 0)
        {
            agregar();
        }
        else
        {
            modificar();
        }
    }   

}
```

Comment: -Leandro Tuttini: Estoy super consiente que mi codigo esta demasiado desordenado, empece a crear metodos por desesperacion de mi falta de conocimiento en realizar diferentes consultas con una misma conexion, por eso ven en mi codigo que para cada consulta abro una conexion, porque para mi entendimiento hasta antes de leer sus respuestas, era abrir una conexion, realizar la consulta y cerrarla
Leere mas detenidamente lo que me comentaste y lo pondre en practica, te aviso cual fue mi resultado. Muchas gracias

Comment: Leandro, muchisimas gracias. Estuve utilizando el codigo que me proporcionaste y funciono bien, tambien logre incorporarlo a agregarPrecios() y unas funciones mas. Tuve algunos problemillas igualmente pero logre solucionarlos por mi cuenta.
Gracias por todo a todos